# How to set up urls in django when there are multiple apps within the same project?

Tags: python, django, url

I am new to django.  I am trying to setup the URLs.  I have 2 apps under a project 'mysite'.  In the urls.py for mysite, I have included the urls from the 2 apps (called 'login' and 'org')

mysite/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', include('login.urls')),
    url(r'^org/', include('org.urls')),
]
```

login/urls.py

```
app_name = 'login'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/$', login_views.signup, name='signup'),
]
```

org/urls.py

```
app_name = 'org'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^organizations/add/$', views.addorg, name='addorg'),
]
```

Having set it up this way, my site URLs become the following:

```
site.com/login/login/signup
site.com/org/organizations/add
```

I would like the URLs so that they are like the following.

```
site.com/login/signup
site.com/organizations/add
```

How do I get the 'includes' to work? Will it work if I change mysite/urls.py to the following?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('login.urls')),
    url(r'^$', include('org.urls')),
]
```

Is there a better way of setting up the URLs when there are multiple apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the setup you describe, the login url would not be `'site.com/login/login/signup'`, but `'site.com/login/signup'`. Where would the second `'login/'` come from?

The solution you suggested,

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('login.urls')),
    url(r'^$', include('org.urls')),
]
```

will generally work if there is no url that occurs identically in both apps. But it is not ideal, since all the patterns in the login urs will be unnecessarily tried for all requests.

Thus, you might want to consider removing the `specific_app.urls` internal prefixes, especially if those prefixes are the same for all views of the app. Leave it to whoever will use and include that app (here: mysite.urls) under which path they want to include the app.

```
# login/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    # no 'login' prefix here. Includers know which app 
    # they are including and how they want do that.
    url(r'^signup/$', login_views.signup, name='signup'),  
]

# org/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    # same: no 'org' prefix
    url(r'^add/$', views.addorg, name='addorg'),
]

# mysite.urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', include('login.urls')),
    url(r'^organizations/$', include('org.urls')),
]
```

The resulting urls will be:

```
site.com/login/signup
site.com/organizations/add
```

Comment: ```from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import include```

Answer (score 4):

**mysite/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', include('login.urls')),
    url(r'^org/', include('org.urls')),
]
```

**login/urls.py**

```
app_name = 'login'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/$', login_views.signup, name='signup'),
]
```

If you put your urls in this way...

Your signup url will be `site.com/login/signup`
The formula is -
[**your site domain** + **urls in main_project/urls.py** + **urls in any_app/urls.py**]

So to correct your organization url - 
you should refactor your **my_site/urls.py** as -

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', include('login.urls')),
    url(r'^organizations/', include('org.urls')),
]
```

and in your **orgs/urls.py** should be

```
app_name = 'org'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^add/$', views.addorg, name='addorg'),
]
```

I hope it helps.