# How to include urls.py from other app without route

Tags: python, django

In django 2.2, I have the main app urls.py as follow:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("logout/", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path('', HomeView.as_view()),
]
```

And I have a different app, called it app2, which I want route/ to be routed into a view

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('route/', RouteMy.as_view()),
]
```

How can I call urls.py from app2 into the main urls.py, properly, without having to do app2/route (so I can have clean URLs and code)

Comment: Check this answer, this might be a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417123/how-to-set-up-urls-in-django-when-there-are-multiple-apps-within-the-same-projec

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up urls in django when there are multiple apps within the same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417123/how-to-set-up-urls-in-django-when-there-are-multiple-apps-within-the-same-projec)

Comment: in django 2.2 instead of url() path is being used

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers but using *path*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("logout/", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path('', include('app2.urls')),
    path('', HomeView.as_view()),
]
```

in app2

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('route/', RouteMy.as_view()),
]
```